# decide whether to update the weights based on a condition on features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, backpropagation

I would like to decide if to train some specific weight, based on feature values.

As a simple attempt I would like to "touch" only the weights between input and 1st layer such that if a condition on a feature *i* holds, then DO NOT train (update) all those weights connecting the 1st layer with input neuron *i*

Let us say I have model like this:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(N, 4)),
layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)])
```

I want everything working normally if I have inputs as [1,2,3,4] with all nonzero values.But, then I would like to provide an example like [1,2,3,0] and make the weights related the 4th neuron of the input layers to stay the same and not updated.I'm trying to simulate a  "missing feature" behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I might be completely wrong. But I think this question makes no mathematical sense. If the input is zero, the gradients will be zero. And so no update to the weights will be performed. Let's make the test.

Let's make some input with a zero:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1.2, 1.1, 0., 2.3, 4.1]], dtype=np.float32)
y = [0.]
```

As you can see, the third value is missing.

Now let's make a forward pass with a random target, and look at the gradients:

```
x = np.array([[1.2, 1.1, 0., 2.3, 4.1]], dtype=np.float32)
y = [0.]

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')])

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    out = model(x)
    loss = tf.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y, out)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

np.round(gradients[0].numpy().tolist(), 2)
```

```
array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.3 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.17, 1.29],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.28, 0.  , 0.  , 0.15, 1.18],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.58, 0.  , 0.  , 0.32, 2.47],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.03, 0.  , 0.  , 0.57, 4.4 ]])
```

All the gradients related to the 3rd column of the input (row 3) are zero. When `optimizer.apply_gradients` will be applied in `model.fit`, nothing will be performed on the weights related to the missing value because the gradients are zero.

Comment: Ok then maybe I'm approacching this the wrong way. My zero in input should mean "missing feature", so, blocking the updating of those weights connecting to it I wanted to somehow disable that part of the network. But I believe you are right, so what I would like to do it is done automatically

Comment: To be more precise, think a simple network that given 3 inputs gives in return their mean value. I would like this to work fine for nonzero inputs, but then if I insert [1 0 5], it will give 2 as mean value (since it is the actual mean value). But I would like it to give 3, since I do not want to consider the 0 (which is my "missing feature"). Any idea how to approach this ?